# How to run Hydra with json response?

Tags: hydra

I've been doing some bug bounty hunting and have been having problems with hydra. So there is a https login form, request is :

```
https://bbsite/crp/login?password=pass&username=admin
```

Problem is that response is in json. So for bad login it is:

```
{"success":false,"greska":"Pogre\u0161no."}
```

So my solution was:

```
hydra  bbsite https-get-form "/crp/login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:{\"success\"\:false,\"greska\"\:\"Pogre\u0161no\"}" -l admin -P /root/Downloads/pass.txt
```

But this is not working, and I have no idea why.
Can anyone suggest solution?

Answer (score 5):

Found solution:

```
hydra  bbsite https-get-form "/crp/login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:F={\"success\"\:false,\"greska\"\:\"Pogre\\\u0161no\"}" -l admin -P /root/Downloads/pass.txt
```

Needed to add F= for fail login.
Needed to escape \ with \.